# Proof of group isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Text of problem:
"You have group (K, ·), and it have two normal subgroups: G and H. $ G⋂H $= {1} and group generated by $G∪H = K. $
Write a proof that mapping alpha : G × H → K defined by: alpha((g, h)) = g·h - is a group isomorphism.
(Hint: first step is to prove, that for all g ∈ G a h ∈ H : $ g^{-1}h^{-1}gh ∈ G ⋂ H.)$

I was able to prove that this is mapping (I think), but I can't prove it is an homomorphism (and that it is injective and surjective).

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha[(g_1,h_1)(g_2,h_2)]= \alpha(g_1g_2,h_1h_2)=  g_1g_2h_1h_2 = g_1h_1g_2h_2 $ (by the hint) = $\alpha[(g_1,h_1)]\alpha[(g_2,h_2)]$.

Since K is generated by G and H, we know there exists $(g,h)$ such that $\alpha[(g,h)]=k, \forall k \in K$, so $\alpha$ is surjective.

And if $\alpha[(g_1,h_1)]=\alpha[(g_2,h_2)]$, then $g_1h_1=g_2h_2$.  Can you finish the injectivity?

Comment: Isn't it the injectivity already?

Comment: I tried to prove injectivity through kernel. Ker alpha must consist from one element: (1,1). alpha(a,b) = ab = 1 for kernel. Either a and b = 1, or a = b^(-1). But b^(-1) must be in the same group in which b, so a and b in the same group. But this is true only for 1. Is there any error in this thought?

Answer (score 1):

Since $g^{-1}h^{-1}g \in H$ (by the normality of $H$ in $K$), this implies $g^{-1}h^{-1}gh \in H$.  Similarly this product is in $G$ by the normality of $G$ in $K$, so the product is in $G \cap H = \{1\}$. Thus $gh = hg$; elements in $G$ commute with those in $H$.  This is what makes the given mapping a homomorphism, since you then have $$\alpha[(g_1,h_1)(g_2,h_2)] = \alpha[(g_1g_2,h_1h_2)] = g_1g_2h_1h_2 = g_1h_1g_2h_2 = \alpha[(g_1,h_1)] \alpha[ (g_2,h_2)]$$

Comment: I understood that I need to prove gh = hg in process of solving it. But I don't understand the connection between first sentence and second one: why the fact that product is in crossing of G and H implies that gh = hg?

Comment: Since $g^{-1}h^{-1}gh \in G \cap H = \{1\}$, this implies that  $g^{-1}h^{-1}gh = 1$.  Multiply on the left by $g$ to get $h^{-1}gh = g$, then multiply on the left by $h$ to get $gh = hg$.